# Efficient way compare data in matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have the following issue. I have to compare data in a matrix (datatable or dataframe) using the following function:

```
Q <- function(j){
        
        # j = (1:dim(x)[1])[1]
        Q1 <- c()
        for(i in 2:ncol(x)){
        # i = 2
        item <- x[j,1]
        indices <- which(x[,i] == item)
     
        items <- x[1:indices, i]
        Q1 <- c(Q1, items)
     
        }
   
     return(Q1)
   
  }
```

For example with a data like this:

```
tablero <- data.frame(t1 = c(1,2,3),
                      t2 = c(3,1,2),
                      t3 = c(3,2,1))
```

I get this output:

```
Q(1) = 3 1 3 2 1
Q(2) = 3 1 2 3 2
Q(3) = 3 3
```

The thing is that i have a big matrix with of 50.000 rows and 7 columns and that function is too slow and use a lot of memory. Is there a more optimal way in memory use and speed to do that same thing?

Comment: Could you explain in a few words what the function is doing?

Comment: The idea is that for each number in column 1 (t1), you look in the other columns where that number is. And you want to keep al the numbers that are above the one you are looking, including the one you are seeing. For example, if you start with 1 in t1, you go to t2 and see that only the 2 is not above 1, so you keep with 1 and 3. Next you see t3 and you see that 2 and 3 are above 1, so you keep 3, 2 and 1. So joining both list you get that Q(1) is a vector with 3, 1, 3, 2 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `sapply` and `apply` functions to loop through your data. This may be more performant than your function which relies on a `for` loop. The code returns a list.

```
sapply(tablero[,1],
       FUN = function(x){
         unlist(apply(tablero[,-1],
                      2,
                      FUN = function(y) y[1:which(y == x)]))
       })

# [[1]]
# t21 t22 t31 t32 t33 
# 3   1   3   2   1 

# [[2]]
# t21 t22 t23 t31 t32 
# 3   1   2   3   2 
 
# [[3]]
# t2 t3 
# 3  3
```

Comment: Unfortunately when i executed the code with this part for a large matrix, it didn't improve the speed or memory usage.